# How to include a variable value in an html element. Tried ${var} but didn't work

Tags: javascript, html

```
var a = 20;
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Your variable is ${a}";
```

Comment: you need to be using template literals (backticks) not quotes

Comment: change your string to `\`Your variable is ${a}\``

Comment: Thank you so much guys, wish you good luck and a healthy environment @AnanthDev,

Comment: and @KreuterCode